# Is it possible to buy an Apple product in the UK and return it in the US?

Tags: ipad, warranty

Is it possible to buy an Apple product, like an iPad mini, in the UK and return it in the US? And vice versa?

Comment: This might be a good place to start: http://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More reading on [Apple discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4393125?start=0&tstart=0) indicates that the warranties are not honored internationally for iPads and iPhones. If you buy somewhere and it breaks, you will likely have to send it back to the country of purchase. Apparently, this is because most countries have their own warranty laws.